# Android use Drawer layout inside Scroll view

Tags: android, android-scrollview, drawerlayout

**When i am trying to use drawer layout inside scroll view my App Crashes**

***Stack Trace:***

```
06-07 14:35:30.482 18292-18292/com.example.mmido.trivelgob2b E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mmido.trivelgob2b, PID: 18292
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.
 at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1036)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16971)
 at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1237)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
 at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:326)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16971)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16971)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
 at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16971)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16971)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16971)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16971)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2337)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16971)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2254)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1315)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1513)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1192)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6172)
 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5398)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:940)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I was using the root view is scroll view but after search i found that i should make the root layout is linear layout then **scrollview** containing drawer layout and it's content . I tried that but my app still crashes with the same stack trace.

***My XML:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"

    tools:context=".Admin.Airlines.EditAirlineActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/header"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/internetstatus"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/sub_drawer">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/mainContent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/basic_background_v2">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Name:"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:id="@+id/textView3" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/airline_edit_name"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
                    android:textColorHint="#C0C0C0"
                    android:hint=" Name"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/textbox_border" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Arabic Name:"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:id="@+id/textView4" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/airline_edit_arabic_name"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
                    android:textColorHint="#C0C0C0"
                    android:hint="Arabic Name"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/textbox_border" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Short Name:"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:id="@+id/textView5" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/airline_edit_short_name"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
                    android:textColorHint="#C0C0C0"
                    android:hint="Short Name"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/textbox_border" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Code:"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:id="@+id/textView6" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/airline_edit_code"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
                    android:textColorHint="#C0C0C0"
                    android:hint="Code"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/textbox_border" />


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:id="@+id/air_line_edit_img"
                    android:onClick="SelectImage"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/airline_edit_btn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="Save"
                    android:background="@drawable/red_btn"
                    style="@style/button_text"
                    android:onClick="EditAirline"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <include layout= "@layout/menu"/>
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edited**

that is what i tried but still the error exists

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"

    tools:context=".Admin.Airlines.EditAirlineActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/header"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/internetstatus"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/sub_drawer">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/mainContent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/basic_background_v2">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Name:"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:id="@+id/textView3" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/airline_edit_name"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
                    android:textColorHint="#C0C0C0"
                    android:hint=" Name"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/textbox_border" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Arabic Name:"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:id="@+id/textView4" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/airline_edit_arabic_name"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
                    android:textColorHint="#C0C0C0"
                    android:hint="Arabic Name"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/textbox_border" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Short Name:"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:id="@+id/textView5" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/airline_edit_short_name"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
                    android:textColorHint="#C0C0C0"
                    android:hint="Short Name"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/textbox_border" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Code:"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:id="@+id/textView6" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/airline_edit_code"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textColor="#C0C0C0"
                    android:textColorHint="#C0C0C0"
                    android:hint="Code"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/textbox_border" />


                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:id="@+id/air_line_edit_img"
                    android:onClick="SelectImage"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/airline_edit_btn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="Save"
                    android:background="@drawable/red_btn"
                    style="@style/button_text"
                    android:onClick="EditAirline"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <include layout= "@layout/menu"/>
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing wrong layout, make DrawerLayout top view of other views, must be something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- here insert your scrollview and all views you need for this page this is actually your page -->

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: i added it to the question  now  you can see it

Comment: hehe.. you are now using two )) remove internal, and leave only one - top level

Comment: Oooh i didn't relize that ...works well now thank you